# Existence of solution of the given ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've an ODE,
$ \frac{du}{dt} = t \log t$

I need to find the particular solution at $(0,0)$

I solved the equation and got,
$u = \frac{t^2}{2} \log t - \frac{t^{2}}{4} + c$

$\log$ function is not defined at $0$, so I took the limit of $\frac{t^2}{2} \log t$ at $0$ and it is $0$, so $c$ is 0.
Is it right way. This solution is defined in small neighborhood of $0$, which I've found using limit.
Can we say that it is particular solution at $(0,0)?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that looks correct. If you extend the domain of the ODE to the whole time axis via
$$
\dot u(t)=t\ln|t|,
$$
then the right side is continuous everywhere and the usual claims on integration give the existence of the solution, like for any other ODE/quadrature problem $\dot u(t)=f(t)$ with a continuous $f$.